# Have you ever had a requirement for a non-Gregorian calendar date, in a database application?

Tags: database, date, gregorian-calendar

Context: I notice that the major databases support only the Gregorian calendar. Thus, it would seem difficult to build a database app with anything other than the Gregorian calendar.

If you have ever used a non-Gregorian date in a database app, I would be curious to know the context of your use case.

For example, if you live in India, what percentage (roughly speaking) of software built in India would use a non-Gregorian calendar? Is it common, or rare? Does the lack of support for non-Gregorian calendars annoy you?

Comment: "Have it on my desk by the 10th of Thermador"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used to work with a large group of Persians.  They used the Gregorian calendar for everyday sorts of things:  work, personal life, etc., but knew off the top of their heads how to convert to the Persian calendar—used, seemingly, mostly for ceremonial purposes.

Comment: It's hard to tell, but in practice it seems like the great majority of software is written only with the Gregorian Calendar in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Some suppliers use Julian dates to represent expiration dates on products, but they're so simple that no special software support is needed.